# Microsoft teams calls get contacts

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

as per this link

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/view-or-add-contacts-in-teams-4828b70a-0194-4272-9895-cfa9468273cf

I can add new contacts , I need to know how can i get these contacts using Graph API. When i send the following request using online Graph Explorer

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members I can get the list of all members of the specified group(team) but the contacts i added using the desktop app of Microsoft teams are not retrieved. obviously these contacts are not the member of team , they are just contacts not members.

I need to know how can i retrieve these contacts using microsoft Graph API.

Comment: Please check the Microsoft graph api snippets sample. You can find implementation of all basic operations in it.
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-snippets-sample

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Teams Contacts is a superset of contacts from [me/contacts Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list-contacts?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs) and additional contacts in substrate data service( This is not accessible publicly).

So you can start with /me/contacts API. In the long run it will be consolidated under a single API